# Input Class in template

Tags: ee, classes

Is it possible to use the EE Classes within a template?

Are they only available for add-on development?

Thanks,
Patrick

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd need to create an add-on to use them, but creating a plugin is simple enough and if you needed something beefier you could always build a module. Also, depending on what you're trying to do, someone may have already solved it so search around at [Devot-ee](http://devot-ee.com) for potential add-ons.

Comment: Good advice, thank you! I came across a couple posts regarding the use of CodeIgniter's classes without building an EE plugin. http://paramoredigital.com/blog/harnessing-the-power-of-codeigniter-in-expressionengine-2.0 & http://venodesigns.net/2011/05/07/when-expressionengine-defaults-are-not-enough/ ... I'd much rather build a plugin but these two posts opened my eyes to other possibilities. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Along the lines of what Wes said about an existing add-on that might do what you need:

[Mo' Variables](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/mo-variables) makes a lot of what the Input Class provides available in your templates (ie, GET, POST, GET and POST, and Cookies). It's a very useful add-on.

Comment: Mo' Variables is exactly what I was lookin' for. I started building a similar plugin before seeing your post. Thank you. Now to find out if it offers the xss option for GET variables.